# Can't parse XML with DOM in android

Tags: android, xml, dom

I am having some trouble parsing XML in Android from an URL. I don't know if it's the XML parsing that's the problem or only when I am trying to show it on the screen because

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ANDROIDXMLActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stopNumbers));
```

wont show anything. The code below works perfectly in a java program.

URL: http://maps.travelsouthyorkshire.com/iGNMSearchService.asmx/FindObjectsWithinExtent?xMin=435360&yMin=387260&xMax=435960&yMax=387860&zoomLevel=0

```java
    try {
        ArrayList<Double> xCords = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> yCords = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<String> stopNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> bussLocations = new ArrayList<String>();
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder
                .parse(new URL(
                        "http://maps.travelsouthyorkshire.com/iGNMSearchService.asmx/FindObjectsWithinExtent?xMin=435360&yMin=387260&xMax=435960&yMax=387860&zoomLevel=0")
                        .openStream());

        // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList listOfObjects = doc.getElementsByTagName("iGNMObject");
        for (int s = 0; s < listOfObjects.getLength(); s++) {
            Node firstPersonNode = listOfObjects.item(s);

            if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element firstPersonElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;
                NodeList stopNumList = firstPersonElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("StopNumber");
                Element ageElement = (Element) stopNumList.item(0);
                if (ageElement != null) {
                    NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();

                    String stop = ((Node) textAgeList.item(0))
                            .getNodeValue().trim();
                    stopNumbers.add(stop);

                    // ------
                    // -------
                    NodeList xPosList = firstPersonElement
                            .getElementsByTagName("XPosition");
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element) xPosList.item(0);
                    NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();

                    String temp2 = ((Node) textFNList.item(0))
                            .getNodeValue().trim();
                    double x = Double.parseDouble(temp2);
                    xCords.add(x);

                    // -------
                    NodeList yPosList = firstPersonElement
                            .getElementsByTagName("YPosition");
                    Element lastNameElement = (Element) yPosList.item(0);
                    NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
                    String temp3 = ((Node) textLNList.item(0))
                            .getNodeValue().trim();
                    double y = Double.parseDouble(temp3);
                    yCords.add(y);

                    // ----

                    NodeList stopAkaList = firstPersonElement
                            .getElementsByTagName("StopAka");
                    Element stopAka = (Element) stopAkaList.item(0);
                    NodeList textStopAKAList = stopAka.getChildNodes();
                    String plats = ((Node) textStopAKAList.item(0))
                            .getNodeValue().trim();
                    bussLocations.add(plats);
                } else {

                }

            }// end of if clause
        }// end of for loop with s var

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ANDROIDXMLActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stopNumbers));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

}
    }

Comment: What do you mean stopNumbers.add("2") is ignored? Does it "skip" this line of code when debugging?

Comment: "1" and "2" is added to the list but not the rest

Comment: Have you debugged to step through this code to see exactly what happens? My guess is that listOfObjects.size() == 0 or something.

Comment: I tested this code and it works ok for the stopNumbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "stop", and 6 correctly printed out). The code doesn't compile as such because you have omitted declarations for the stopNumbers, xPos, and yPos. Post us all the code + how you test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I had forgot to add internet permission in the manifest.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as accepted when the system allows you to do so. Also, would you mind elaborating on this answer a bit?

Comment: Well, the application couldn't access the URL beaucse it didn't have the permission to do so. This caused the program to catch an exception instead of reading through the XML url thus leaving my lists null and nothing to show on the screen.

Comment: The athor did not allow his Application to access the internet through the INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifext.xml. This question has nothing to do with XML parsing. 

The application has no XML to parse, probably due to the horrible exception handling at the end of his code snippet.